# Antlr4 how to avoid syntax errors with anything between quotes rule?

Tags: regex, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I'm trying to build my own dsl in order to create custom rules to match a given json object.

for this purpose I've created so far two kind of rules with the following grammar:

```
grammar RuleGrammar;

def: 'Def(' jsonrule ')';
jsonrule: regex|composite;
regex: '"' code '"';
composite: '[' jsonrule ('&&'jsonrule)* ']';
code: ANY+;

ANY: ( '\\"' | .);

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip();
```

This grammar fails with a syntax error when the "code" of the regex contains characters '[' or ']', such as:

```
Def("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
line 1:5 extraneous input '[' expecting ANY
```

I see this has to do with the definition of the composite rule, which has ']' in it.

Is there a way to avoid the syntax error without escaping the brackets in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regex` and `code` should be lexer rules. Besides, `code` is greedy, so it'll probably consume too much input.

Write the `REGEX` rule like that instead:

```
REGEX: '"' ('\\' ["\\] | ~["\\\r\n])* '"';
```

If you want an explanation for the error you get, it's because the `[` character is an implicitly defined token, as you used it in the `composite` rule. It doesn't get recognized as `ANY` because of the lexer priority rules.